# Wagtail - Expand Orderable / InlinePanel functionality

Tags: python, django, wagtail

What I am trying to do is attempted before in different forms: Add Taxonomy to Wagtail, a feature present in most other popular CMSs (Drupal as "Taxonomy", Craft as "Categories, ...). I know Wagtail has some type of implementation called "Collections" but it is not as fully fledged as other implementations and its interface does not cater to large trees.

My approach: Build upon `Orderable` models, as they already give us a nice way to order child items related to an other model (think Menu -> MenuItems). Together with `InlinePanel`, `Orderable`s give you a nice interface to manage your main Taxonomy name and all of its "nodes".

Yet, an `Orderable` is one-dimensional, it only goes up or down via a `sort_order` column on the `Orderable` model. My idea is to provide a second dimension, to go left or right, with a `parent` column. A super simple data model:

```py
class NestedOrderable(Orderable):
    parent = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['parent', 'sort_order']
```

Now in the `InlinePanel`, the sort order gets inserted as a hidden field on each child item. I am trying to now find a way to get this `parent` attribute to be included into the HTML rendering as well, as a hidden input in the same way as `sort_order` does.

The `InlinePanel` injects the `sort_order` field this way:

```py
subform.fields[ORDERING_FIELD_NAME].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

And updates the model on save. However, I can inject this `parent` field myself:

```py
subform.fields['parent'] = forms.IntegerField()
subform.fields['parent'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

This of course does render the hidden field, but has no relation to the model and gets completely ignored when saving.

So, I guess my main question is: What is the correct way to expand `InlinePanel` so my `parent` column is automatically injected as a `HiddenField` and saved/retrieved correctly from the database?

When this `parent` column gets saved correctly my feeling is that I have the main parts running to get a tree setup going. The (HTML) interface side of things is mainly JavaScript magic to render the tree, drag/drop and update the hidden inputs accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably resolved long ago, but for anyone reading, you just need to pick up the data in the form field and assign it in the clean()

```
self.parent = self.data['parent']
```

Hidden fields are not part of the clean/save process.

What I'd love to find is how to access the instance of the clusterable model that creates the orderable and pass parameters from that. I can override the for class, the parent form class and meta class, and the form builder class, but none of these get me access to the parent object from the child orderable.